# whats the best way to write a php mysql function?

Tags: php, mysql, function

i want to retrieve information from my database quite a lot throughout my app, i was thinking it would be easier to write function, so i can access it anytime, what is the best way to write one! thanks :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope this helps, you have to pass variables to a function, then use that variable to retrieve something from your database! i.e.

```
function getUserInfo($username) {

                $query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '$username'";
                $result = mysql_query($query);
                if (!mysql_num_rows($result)) return false;
                $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
                return $row;

            }
```

Comment: -1 That's just asking for SQL injection, unless all of your input data is sanitised before anything uses it.

Comment: cheers for the code worked perfectly, thanks @cez for leeting know about security, i have escaped the statment before i pass on to the function!! :))

Comment: if you your escaping all GPC such as recursive variables then you have issues with your application down the line.

Comment: can you clarify what u mean, the $username variable, is sanitised before its pass on to the function, to do anything else

Answer (score 0):

- mysql_query() - simple, function interface
- PDO - OOP, statement preparation, simple to learn and good to use
- ORM - Doctrine, Propel, hard for beginners but powerful at later stage.

Answer (score 0):

Integrate a class into PDO then integrate your methods into the Database Object

Examples:

```
class Database extends PDO
{
    //Override __construct for PDO
    function __construct()
    {
        Here you assembly your PDO Constructor
        parent::__construct($dsn,$username,$password,$driver_options);
    }    
}
```

Based on that you can simple do:

```
$Database = new Database(); //Where as your Database class is now combined with PDO:
```

As a follow up you can do classes like so now:

```
class DB_Table_Users extends Database
{

    public function getByLocation($location)
    {
        $statement = $this->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE location = :location");
        $statement->bindValue(':location',$location);
        $statement->execute();
        return $statement;
    }

    public function getByDate($int_date)
    {
        $statement = $this->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE reg_date > :int_date");
        $statement->bindValue(':int_date',$int_date);
        $statement->execute();
        return $statement;
    }

}
```

and use like so:

```
$Users = new DB_Table_Users;
$statement = $Users->getByLocation('uk');

foreach($row as $statement->fetchObject())
{
    //..
}
```

This has some more structure to the database relations and will keep your tables specific to a class.

Tip: you can also use `__get` and `__set` within your `DB_Table_XXXX` so that within your methods you can fetch as an object to your own table.

Comment: thanks for a great anwser, :)), how about if i wanted to join tables!!

Comment: well lets say you had 2 tables, `Users` & `Posts` and you was fetching the data for `User + Post` you would create a specific method in `DB_Table_Users` for that, otherwise if your fetching `Posts + Users` witch is the what you would do for lets so StackOverflow's Index page, that would come under `DB_Table_Posts`, if you really want to get into an Advanced form of what im doing then you should look at the ORM Concepts

Comment: Also, answers that you find useful you should up vote them using the ^ arrow to the left of the post.